# html5 web audio api save the output after applying filters on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, web-audio-api

It seems to be very simple but I am not able understand how to do it.
I have simple app where I apply some filters on audio file, I can listen to those effects in real time but now I want to save that audio file with all effects on server. How do I save it?

Note: I am using recorder.js, I can download audio file here but instead of that I need to upload it on my application server.

Update:
I solved issue of saving file on server. But now when I am trying to save filtered output using recorder.js but when I input output to recorder it gives noise sound. Code sample - http://jsfiddle.net/d5Nw7/

```
function startRecording() {
soundSource.start(context.currentTime);
recorder = new Recorder(myNodes.volume);
recorder.record();
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs.

The API is pretty straight-forward, but leave a comment if you have any questions and I can help you out.

Comment: thanks Kevin. I am already using recorder.js. I am facing 2 challenges here 1. Instead of downloading audio file, how I can save it on server, I use ruby on rails. 2. How do I pass my filtered output to recorder.js?

Comment: I found one answer https://github.com/lempere/Recorderjs but it is using php, I tried to convert into rails but it throws error on decode, saying undefined conversion.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, okay. Your answer didn't originally mention anything about sending it to the server. I'm not really a Rails guy, so I can't really offer much advice there. You might want to add a Rails tag to your post. Sounds like this isn't quite a Web Audio question.

Comment: okay.. how abt my second que - How do I pass my filtered output to recorder.js?

Comment: Just pass the last node in your signal flow as the first argument to a new Recorder instance. So if you had `BufferSourceNode -> GainNode -> ScriptProcessorNode -> AnalyserNode -> context.destination`, then you'd  pass the `AnalyserNode` as the first argument. `new Recorder(myAnalyser)`.

Comment: I tried new Recorder(myAnalyser) but as soon as I play sound which is also input to recorder, I hear loud noise. I think same sound is being played from 2 destination, any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to offer anything particularly insightful at this point without seeing your code. If you can post a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem I'm sure myself or someone else will be able to get you sorted out.

Comment: I tried to put it on jsfiddle but it doesn't work because of js file call inside another js file. You may look at sample code here http://jsfiddle.net/d5Nw7/.

Comment: OMG!! I think it doesn't work on linux properly. I tested same code on mac & windows and it worked fine!! 2 sleepless nights!! Can you please confirm this? here is link for my app http://dry-beyond-5865.herokuapp.com/editing.html